# Java - how to insert into final list

Tags: java, list, collections, insert, final

I have a list of objects I need to operate on.

Depending on the object, the operation will result in new object that need be placed in order of creation JUST before the object that was operated on.

Under normal circumstances, I'd create a new list and then simply switch the lists. This is, however, not possible in this particular case because the list is final.

Is there a more elegant solution than to create a new list, overwrite the existing list and then add as many elements as are left when all existing elements of the old list are overwritten?

**UPDATE: psuedocode**

I am looking for something like this:

```
class Some{ //provided
    public final List<Thing> finalList = ...
}

class MyClass{
    void handle(Thing t, List<Thing> newThings){
        //do something to t
        //probably create and add new instances of Thing to newThings
    }

    void handle(Some s){
        for(Thing t : s.finalList){
            List<Thing> newThings = new ArrayList<>();
            handle(t,newThings);
            for(Thing nt : newThings){
                //insert nt into s.finalList s.th. it is immediately precedes t
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: pls provide some code

Comment: Please provide some code as said by Cootri

Comment: Depending on the List implementation, `add(int index, E element)` might be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) and its `previous()` method to insert before the current element. Don't forget to `next()` back to where you were initially.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you list is final you can add elements to it.
Here is an example:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestList {

    private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestList testList = new TestList();
        testList.createTestData();
        testList.insertInMiddle();
        testList.printAll();
    }

    private void printAll() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
    }

    //Add a item between 1.2
    private void insertInMiddle() {
        //Use ListIterator or your current logic to find the right index to insert at
        list.add(1, new String("1.2"));
    }

    private void createTestData() {
        list.add(new String("1"));
        list.add(new String("2"));
    }
}
```